# How can I do xpath injection in this code?

Tags: xpath, inject

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="k"> <br>
<input type="password" name="p"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="gonder"> <br>
</form>
```

This code has xpath injection and the xml database of this code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kullanicilar>
    <kullanici>
        <id>1</id>
        <kAdi>yetkili</kAdi>
        <parola>1999yetkili!</parola>
        <bilgi>merhaba dunya</bilgi>
```

How can I do xpath injection in this code?

I read other topics but it didn't work or I didn't understand.

I'm waiting for ur help

Comment: I think you should construct sample XPath but generally you would want something along the line ...parola[text()="+password+"... in the code and the value to subvert the XPath would be  ,xxx" or 1=1 or "b"="b, right?

Comment: I have tried the values ​​before
--  k = adc 'or' 1 '=' 1 'or' 2 '=' 2
p = adc 'or' 1 '=' 1 'or' 2 '=' 2  -- but it didn't work

Comment: I need a second user(kullanici)